# How to use translation functions inside WordPress page

Tags: translation, multi-language

I am using several language files(`.po`, `.mo`) for multi-lingual translation purposes. The sources root for these files is specified as the root of my theme directory, and the translations work fine for `.php` files located inside this directory tree. But how do I do the same for content included in the WordPress pages?

I got around the problem of including PHP code inside the page by using the `Insert PHP` plugin. So for example I can do this,

```
[insert_php]
    _e('Hello', 'my_domain');
[/insert_php]
```

Since the content of WordPress pages are saved in the database under the `wp_posts` table, I cannot add that as a source for the `.po` file. So how can I implement translation for the content directly included in WordPress pages?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a plugin that uses the `eval()` function, you could write a simple shortcode to handle translations. something like this:

The issue you would face is that the strings wouldn't be picked up automatically by a tool like POEdit, you would need to manually add the strings to the translation PO files.

```
/**
 * [__]My string to translate[/__]
 * 
 * @param $atts
 * @param $content
 * @return string|void
 */
function my_translate_shortcode( $atts ,$content ){

    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
        'textdomain' => 'mytextdomain'
    ], $atts );


    return __( $content, $atts['textdomain'] );

}
add_shortcode( '__',  'my_translate_shortcode' );
```